# Ableton Live - expression pedal to affect currently selected track

Tags: midi, ableton-live

I have the FCB1010.
I would like to press a pedal, which would switch to a track, and then, when I use the volume pedal affect only the selected track's volume.

Can this be done? It will be helpful to control the mix while playing a guitar.